# How to make imageflow to link to content or product using drupal views

Tags: javascript, drupal, view, imageflow

I've created a view, added the specific path and used 'rewrite results' to output the field as a link > path. This gives me the intended HTML view format. When I change to imageflow and one of the images, the behavior changes to open a larger version of the image (imageflow default behavior).

As I see it, it's an imageflow overwrite, and the plugin allows you to set an `onClick` parameter. I'm trying different values to try to make it link to content. This tends to break imageflow or not link at all.

Any similar experience or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What is the kind of your field? Image, title?

Link the field to its node and then use this code inside the "OnClick Override" settings:

```
function() {window.open(this.url, '_blank');} // Or _parent to open it normally
```

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? Did the above help you?

Comment: The documentation provides the string
'function() { document.location = this.url; }'
but doesn't work either.
The solution found was to use a different drupal module jQFX.
The links work without the need of the onClick statement.

Answer (score -1):

The solution found was to use a different Drupal module jQFX. The links work without the need of the onClick statement. Unfortunately, the option reflex doesn't seem to work.